# Why Meteor put all the js in the beginning?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm a new player in Meteor, just did some easy examples and I realized that all the script tags are imported in the beginning of the body tag. According to my experience and yahoo's 14 rules, js files should be imported in the end, Why is that? And in what circumstances js files should be imported in the beginning?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In traditional websites, where the HTML is sent as-is from the server, placing external Javascript files near the bottom of the `<body>` tag speeds up the page rendering and improves user experience because the static page, along with it's included external assets such as images, is loaded and rendered before the scripts finish loading.

In Meteor however, the HTML is built by Javascript in the client's browser, so all the scripts need to be loaded for the page to render anyway. Moreover, usually there is basically nothing other than scripts in the `<body>` of a Meteor app's HTML source anyway.